# Nombre de los archivos al guardar en C# MVC (BodyPart)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy programando un input file con angularJS y c# MVC.
A la hora de revisar la carpeta donde guarda los archivos me los muestra de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Así tengo mi condigo en el controller**

```
    public class SubirHvController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("PostFileWithData")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploadfiles");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);


        var model = result.FormData["jsonData"];
        if (model == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        //TODO: Do something with the JSON data.  

        //get the posted files  
        foreach (var file in result.FileData)
        {
            //TODO: Do something with uploaded file.  
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success!");
    }
}
```

Parece que si están llegando bien los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cualquier opinión sería de mucha ayuda.
Gracias

Comment: Que tecnologia estas utilizando como backend? ASP.net? PHP?

Comment: @Einer estoy usando   ASP.NET

Comment: Web forms o MVC?

Comment: @Einer estoy usando  MVC con capas

Comment: @Camilo López edita la pregunta y muestra tu codigo para poder entender mejor la pregunta y cumpla con [mcve]

Comment: @RaulCacacho Ya solucione la mayoría de los problemas. Voy a editar la pregunta completamente

Comment: //TODO: Do something with uploaded file. ¿De casualidad, aquí te falta algo?

Comment: Te sugiero editar tu pregunta con el código que estás utilizando porque si te está guardando, ese código debería estar y con gusto te damos una mano. Ahora, si nada has investigado, click aquí: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=upload+file+aspnet+mvc+api y a plantar arbolitos mientras aprendes :D

Answer (score 3):

Exactamente. El servidor para evitar pisar archivos y no tener problemas a la hora de guardar, los guarda de esa forma

Si queres saber el nombre real del archivo que envio el usuario, lo tenes en:

```
file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
```

y el nombre que tiene en el servidor es:

```
file.LocalFileName
```

De esa forma, si agregas esa informacion en el `foreach` que recorre lo que vino, vas a saber el nombre de cada archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no he podido entender todavía como hace para guardar el archivo. O sea recuperando el nombre del archivo. Como lo guardo?  estuve revisando en internet y hay algo con SaveAs o algo así. No he podido entender bien como guarda

Comment: @CamiloLópez no entiendo. El archivo ya lo trajiste y lo guardaste. es eso que dice bodypart. Con estas dos propiedades sabes cual es el nombre en el servidor, y cual el nombre que le dio el usuario..

Comment: A la hora de descargar el archivo o mostrarlo. como hago para vincularlo, es decir veo que esta con el nombre de bodypart pero a la hora de vincularlo a una ruta para descargarlo no le encuentro sentido ya que no tiene ni extension ni nombre de archivo logico

Comment: Pero ya descargaste el archivo. Me parece que tenes una confusion, esas dos propiedades que te pase, son las que dicen que nombre de archivo se corresponde con que bodypart...

Answer (score 0):

Si me guardaba bien los archivos, pero no podía cambiar el nombre ni la extensión. Esta fue la solución que encontré por si a alguién le sirve mas adelante.

Cree otra clase y asigne estás lineas de código para poder modificar el nombre de los archivos a mi gusto.

**Clase principal**

```
    public class SubirHvController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("SubirHojaDeVida")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var ruta = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploadfiles");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);


        var datos = new FormDataStreamer(ruta);

        datos.NombreArchivo = MetodosUtiles.ObtenerValorUnico() + "_SolicitudHojaDeVida";

        var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(datos);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success!");
    }

}
```

---

```
    public class FormDataStreamer : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public FormDataStreamer(string rootPath) : base(rootPath)
    {
    }

    public FormDataStreamer(string rootPath, int bufferSize) : base(rootPath, bufferSize)
    {
    }

    public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        var srcFileName = headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
        return NombreArchivo + Path.GetExtension(srcFileName);
    }
}
```